# Can someone explain to me the step by step approach in solving iteration?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def soh(x):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(x):
        if i%2 == 0:
            continue
        for j in range (i):
            counter = counter + i
    return counter

print(soh(5))
```

How to do this question? What is the step by step approach? When you see
if i%2 == 0: continue, what do you do?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What's your question? You've pasted a piece of code (without formatting), but nothing to describe what you're stuck on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's read through and describe the source you provided.

```
def soh(x):
```

define a function object

```
    counter = 0
```

set zero to a new integer variable 'counter' within the scope of 'soh'

```
    for i in range(x):
```

iterate the next block of code, assigning 'i' to the integers zero through, but not including 'x'

```
        if i%2 == 0:
```

check if the remainder of 'i' divided by two is zero

```
            continue
```

do nothing more for this iteration if 'i' is evenly divisible by two

```
        for j in range (i):
```

iterate 'j' from zero to, but not including 'i'

```
            counter = counter + i
```

increment 'counter' by one

```
    return counter
```

return the value of 'counter', leaving the scope of 'soh' and discard all bindings within its scope

```
print(soh(5))
```

execute the function object 'soh', passing the integer five as a parameter, and print its return value to whatever standard out is bound to